# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found

Tags: .net-core, docker

Olá

Tenho o seguinte aplicativo em .net:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou a tentar dockerizar o projecto.

Tenho o seguinte dockerfile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o docker-compose.yml:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a minha versão do dotnet é a 3.1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executo o comando *docker-compose up* é retornado o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Obrigado.

Comment: Consegue adicionar o TodoApp.csproj à pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não está no Docker, mas na mudança para .net core 3.1. Verifique se `TodoApp.csproj` está com .net 2.* ou 3.*. Caso o projeto esteja com uma versão do .net diferente da versão da imagem de container usada, ajuste-os para ter a mesma versão (cuidado que o nome das imagens varia de acordo com a versão do .net).

Caso esteja sempre com o .net 3.*, certifique-se de remover qualquer referência ao meta package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. Mais sobre essa mudança: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references